# How to know what link user clicked on when inside Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: java, android, webview, chrome-custom-tabs

This is possible within a WebView (i.e. using shouldOverrideUrlLoading). Can something like this be achieved when using Chrome Custom Tabs?

Comment: Can we at least know why -1?